# Where to show local work authorization(s) in a resume

Tags: resume, citizenship

I am helping someone with their resume. The person is a citizen of country A, has work permit (and will require sponsorship) in country B and is currently a permanent resident of country C and D. 
When applying for jobs, where and how to show that the candidate is open to relocate to any country (AND will not/require visa sponsorship) ? And more importantly what would be an acceptable resume format to list the authorizations of these many countries.

Comment: From your comment on thursdaygeek's answer, I take it that this resume is *not* being tailored for a specific job application, but rather to publish on a listing site? You might want to clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

That might be better addressed in the cover letter, and listing only the information that is pertinent to the particular job applied for.

If you list it in the resume, and list everything, the important part -- what the current potential employer cares about -- will be surrounded by other information that the hiring manager doesn't care about.  Adding something useless hurts a marketing document.  If it is added to the resume, again, only the part that is appropriate for each particular job should be listed.  That means changing the resume a lot.

Since the cover letter is written specifically for each job anyway, it would be easy to add a couple of sentences or a short paragraph explaining that he or she will be able to legally work, tailoring the legal qualifications to that particular job.

Comment: A lot of career websites (in different countries) dont give the option of a cover letter. What could be done in such cases ?

Comment: So, only one document is allowed to be uploaded?  If that is the case, I would still make a cover letter, but append it to the front of the resume.  But, if a cover letter is really not the norm, that may not be best.  The other option would be to modify the resume and tailor it for each application.  You do only want to list what will help with that particular job, so modifying a resume for each job is acceptable.

Comment: This does not answer the question of _where_ in the resume to list the specific qualifications.